# Number of ways of coloring a K by K grid of cells with N distinct colors

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, coloring

EDIT: I have been working on this for a while now and I can say that a $2\times 2$ grid is such a deceiver because the maximum colors we can do for it is $2$. From $3$, everything breaks as there will always be adjacent cells colored.
Given a $K\times K$ grid of cells and $N$ distinct colors, in how many ways can we color the grid such that no two adjacent cells are colored. That said, if two colors *touch* horizontal or vertical to each other, they are adjacent. That is to be avoided, as some images below show. Of importance are cases where $N$$\le$$K^2$. As you might have imagined, the  $K^2$ defines the possible spaces. It is undesirable to end up with a case where we have too many colors than is the square space. Waste of paint. Anyway, also, each color is used only once. Keeps everything neat.
 
Consider the following $7\times 7$ grid of cells where we are working with $2$ colors. The following coloring's acceptable;
[image]

This, too, is acceptable. Yes, the cells are adjacent, but not horizontally/vertically. 
[image]

However, the coloring below is not acceptable;
[image]

This is also not acceptable;
[image]

How can this be solved?

Comment: The different colors just gives us a factor of $N!$, and then you may as well ask "How many ways are there to color $N$ squares black so that no two black squares are adjacent?" It's a bit simpler, I think. But still not trivial. For $1\times K$ grids, it's not too difficult, but square grids are another story.

Comment: Interesting. What about rectangular grids? What would happen then? But yes, the fact that this is a square grid weighs heavy.

Comment: In general, rectangular grids are, if anything, more difficult than square grids. Just because there is more freedom. That being said, answering for _specific_ recttangular grids, like $1\times K$ (which is pretty easy) and $2\times K$ (which looks like it's a little tricky but not too bad) might be easier than square grids.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed. I would understand why a $1\times K$ grid would be easier to solve than the others - it's just one row; a queue of items - in this case, colors. It is a rectangular grid, no one's denying that. True. However, whether it's a _true_ rectangle is another story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the results for small $K$ and $N$, without the factor of $N!$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
&K\backslash N  &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10 &11 &12 &13 &14 \\
&1 &1 \\                                                
&2 &4 &2 &0 &0 \\                                          
&3 &9 &24 &22 &6 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\                              
&4 &16 &96 &276 &405 &304 &114 &20 &2 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\                  
&5 &25 &260 &1474 &5024 &10741 &14650 &12798 &7157 &2578 &618 &106 &14 &1 &0 
\end{matrix} 
\end{equation}
The count for $N=1$ is obviously $K^2$.  The next few columns appear in OEIS as sequences involving placements of nonattacking wazirs on a chessboard:
[A172225](https://oeis.org/A172225) [A172226](https://oeis.org/A172226) [A172227](https://oeis.org/A172227) [A172228](https://oeis.org/A172228)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but your data claims that in a $3\times 3$ grid where we are supposed to use two colors, there are $0$ possible ways to color. Isn't this incorrect? We could color the top-most-left cell and then the bottom-most-right cell (and several other ways).

Comment: No, for $K=3$ and $N=2$, the count is 24.  I updated the table to show that $K$ is the row and $N$ is the column.

Comment: So you're claiming that a $3\times 3$ grid, using $2$ colors, can be colored in just $24$ different ways? I don't know. I'm rather skeptical about your solution. How can you prove correctness? Since that is a relatively small grid, I did it by hand and ended up having $44$ combinations. I zipped _a few_ of the images [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00349256434267675741). I'm not saying the answer is $44$. I'm just saying your answer of $24$, hence your entire table, might be incorrect.

Comment: $\binom{9}{2}=36$ is a trivial upper bound obtained from considering all pairs of cells.

Comment: I wasn’t able to open your attachment, but I suspect the discrepancy is that my table shows the number of ways to color $N$ of the cells black, as in @Arthur’s comment. To get the full count, you would then need to multiply by $N!$.  For $K=3$ and $N=2$, this would yield $24\cdot 2!=48$ colorings.  For a simpler case, consider $K=N=2$, where my table has a count of 2, but this yields 4 colorings.

Comment: #1. Just checked the link. It (together with the rar file) works fine on my system.

Comment: #2. A case where K = N =2 is a $2\times 2$ grid where we are to use two colors, correct? You posit, "...this yields 4 colorings." That's a daring statement to make, considering I can think of $8$ colorings off-head. Perhaps I am missing something. Multiplying by $2!$. Hmm. Maybe so. So, then, how do you account for the zeroes in your table? From it, we can see that, say, _a $9\times 9$ grid, using  $3$ colors, has 0 possible solutions_. No. There's _at least_ $1$ solution.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify more.

Comment: **_Oh let us be wary of a 2 by 2 lest it mislead us_**

Comment: For $K=N=2$, the two colored cells must be diagonally opposite corners, and there are two choices, as indicated in the table.  Now for each such choice of two cells, assign distinct colors to these cells, yielding four colorings: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&\\&2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2&\\&1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}&1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}&2\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ The table does not include any entries for 9x9. It shows results only up to 5x5.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see I was a bit off on my guess of $8$. It's true, they are $4$, my bad. Regardless, your solution/table is very suspect. A $5\times 5$ grid, using $3$ colors, has $1$ solution? Suspicious! I'm afraid I can't mark it as an answer.

Comment: You are still reading the table backwards. 3x3 with 5 colored cells has one solution (which you would then multiply by $5!$): $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&& 1 \\&1\\1&& 1\end{pmatrix},$$ but 5x5 with 3 colored cells has 1474 solutions (which you would then multiply by $3!$).

Comment: That's $8,844$. Can you prove correctness? Well, working with various applications such as MS Excel and others, I attempted to generate as many identities as I could and ended up having $9,240$ possible colorings (plus or minus a few. Like I said, this was a mediocre approach). They all stick to the requirements. You have less. [Here] is the raw text file. Take a look at it and try to point out _bad_ orderings, if any. If you find no errors, it is highly likely that your solution isn't correct - just as I have been doubting all along.

Comment: I recant. It would seem you are correct. Gentleman, very well indeed!